# MSChart Custom Y Axis Value Range

Tags: c#, mschart

I have some data I need to display using MSChart, I am looking to plot data which is one of the following values taken at a particular datetime:

Low
Low-Medium
Medium
Medium-High
High

So I am looking for datetime along the X axis and the above values on Y

When I try and plot them something like this....

```
mySeries.Points.AddXY(dateA, "Low");
mySeries.Points.AddXY(dateB, "Low-Medium");
mySeries.Points.AddXY(dateC, "Medium");
```

The chart obviously doesn't have any idea that Medium show be a larger bar than Low.

How can I specify this range of values for the Y Axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set numeric values as suggested in [Kyle answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822175/mschart-custom-y-axis-value-range/6822224#6822224) and then change the Y labels e.g.:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(0, 1, "LOW"); 
// it means: on Y range = [0, 1] show the label "LOW" ...

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(2, 3, "MEDIUM");
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(3, 4, "HIGH");
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the different values a numeric value:

```
mySeries.Points.AddXY(dateA, 1); // Low
mySeries.Points.AddXY(dateB, 2); // Low-Medium
mySeries.Points.AddXY(dateC, 3); // Medium
```

I'm not sure how you would show the named values on the Y axis though.

Comment: Thanks, this might do it.. Just need to grasp how to change the Y Label.